# map execute command vim

Tags: vim

I found the following execute command to be useful in vim:

```
:execute "normal! mqA;\<esc>`q"
```

it goes to normal mode, then it makes a mark "q" at cursor position,
goes to end of the line and adds a semicolon ";", then it goes to
normal mode again and returns to the original cursor position.

How could I map all this command to a key called "scc"?

I have tried:

```
imap scc <Esc>:execute "normal! mqA;\<esc>`q"<CR>
```

however it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `:execute - normal`, you can simply do (and use the "noremap" form):

```
inoremap scc <Esc>mqA;<Esc>`q
```

But your map keys are not very good chosen(?), try e.g. `<F3>` for function key 3.

Comment: your are faster. :) I +1 yours and remove mine.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I'm quick :)

Answer (score 2):

Others have dealt with the core problem but I should had that, instead of creating an alphabetical mark, you could use a "context mark":

```
inoremap <something> <Esc>m`A;<Esc>``
```

Using an alphabetical mark is not wrong, mind you, but I think they are more useful elsewhere.