# What is wrong with this line? nnoremap <C-[> :execute "normal! A{{{\<Esc>"<CR>

Tags: vim

I am trying to add this to my vimrc but I am getting problems one it inserts `{{{` at the beginning of my vimrc whenever I open it and also it apparently has 'c' in the regiser as the last pressed key so it deletes the first 2 lines when I press <kbd>j</kbd>

And when I run the command it complains that

> "A{{{\ is missing a quotation mark and is not a command.

Comment: Nothing. Replacing `\<Esc>` with `\e` will do the job. BUT we already have a good answer here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave me tip. [map execute command vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964492/map-execute-command-vim)

You don't need use `:execute "normal! ..."` if you are using `nnoremap`. This will work. 
`nnoremap <C-[> A{{{<Esc><CR>`

Comment: Thanks! That is working although when I open up vim it shows a 'c' in the bottom corner like it is the last key I had pressed and then moving at all deletes some lines any idea where the 'c' is coming from? If I comment out the line then it doesn't happen anymore, so I am assuming it is that line.

Comment: I got it to work with <leader>[ but using <C-[> adds a c key press when I open the file so I can't use that mapping for now any ideas as to why that is?